# Two definitions of Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

i would have a question realted to this previous question [Comparing Lebesgue integral and Riemann Stieltjes integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151858/comparing-lebesgue-integral-and-riemann-stieltjes-integral).

It is shown in previous question that, for **positive function** $f$ we can get by bootstrapping method equality

$\int fd\mu_{g}=\sum_{n}f(x_{n})\Delta g(x_{n}),$

where $g$ is a right continuous, increasing step function on $\mathbb{R}$ with  countable discontinuous points $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$.

But how could one show, that it is true for **any** measurable funtion $f$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Every measurable function is a difference of two non-negative measurable functions.

Comment: Any measurable $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ can be written as $f = f^+ - f^-$, where $f^+ = \max(f,0)$ and $f^- = \max(-f,0) = - \min(f, 0)$. (See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts). Then $f^+$ and $f^-$ are both unsigned (aka "positive", actually non-negative), so you can "get by bootstrapping method equality".

Comment: Perfect, thanks i was thinking about it, but was not very sure. Could i have another question? :....the guy there wrote that -  It can be show that $\mu_{g}(A)=\sum_{x_{n}\in A}\Delta g(x_{n})$, but this is not very clear to me how could i show that.